# Authentication using Windows cmd and Cypher Shell for Neo4j

Tags: authentication, cmd, neo4j, passwords, cypher-shell

When I connect to Cypher Shell using cmd, I type this:

`bin\cypher-shell -u neo4j`

Immediately after, I'm prompted for a password. I enter the password and connect to Cypher Shell. Yay!

Now, if I try to connect to Cypher Shell using cmd with this command:

`bin\cypher-shell -u neo4j - p <password>`

I'm given the error:

`The client is unauthorized due to authentication failure`

Can somebody explain to me why that is?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Use the full connection string for cypher-shell can be in the format:

`bin\cypher-shell -a <connection-URI>://<username>:<password>@<host><:port>`
or
`bin\cypher-shell -a <connection_uri> -u <username> -p <password>`

For example:
`bin\cypher-shell -a neo4j://neo4juser:neo4jpassword@127.0.0.1:7687`
or
`bin\cypher-shell -a neo4j://127.0.0.1:7687 -u neo4juser -p neo4jpassword`